# Lotus Notes Rules Exception

Tags: lotus-notes, email-filter

How can I prevent rules from acting on emails addressed (To/CC/BCC) to me?
*Exception* is not working as expected.

Here's what I have:

```
When:
To or CC contains listname@list.company.com
Except when:
To or Cc contains first.last@company.com
move to folder listname
```

where, first.last@company.com is my email address.
A test email addressed to the list and myself went into the folder *listname* despite the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lotus Notes unfortunately (for the user) Mail- addresses can have two different formats:

External mails will have **first.last@company.com** as recipient address. Internal mails will have **CN=First Last/O=YourOrg@YourDominoDomain** as recipient. You need to exclude both addresses to successfully exclude mails directly sent to you.

The same is true for group- addresses: external: **listname@list.company.com**, internal: **listname@YourDominoDomain**

Comment: Just to clarify: first.last@company.com is not the only format for Lotus Notes external email addresses. There are many different formats that can be used, and in fact multiple formats can be allowed simultaneously.

Comment: Good point. Every single user can have multiple mailaddresses in different formats. i just chose first.last because this was used in the question.